# Bold text from exposed filters

Tags: 7, views

I'm using an exposed filter in views to find nodes that contain that word in the body field.

I would like to show that word in the body in bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using [search_excerpt](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.module/function/search_excerpt/7) function.

for eg:

in your views tpl file add the following code

```
 <?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): 

      $keys = $_GET['body_value'];
      $row = search_excerpt($keys, $row);
 ?>
```

it will highlight the searched word, see the screenshot below

[image]